# How to print a group of list type variables in the form of a table in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, text-parsing

I'm parsing some text files and extracting required information out of it and right now I'm printing it to console as below:

```
A
123USD
01-02-1994 to 01-02-1995
12345
345USD
01-03-1998 to 01-05-1999
34567
Sheet1

B
892USD
24-12-2001 to 12-11-2003
34789
778USD
02-04-2003 to 01-03-2004
8765
334USD
12-08-2002 to 12-10-2003
12345
Sheet2
```

Right now, I'm storing these values in respective `list` type variables but what I need to achieve is printing that same information in the below form:

```
Letter  Price       Time                        Money   Name
A       123USD      01-02-1994 to 01-02-1995    12345   Sheet1
A       345USD      01-03-1998 to 01-05-1999    34567   Sheet1
B       892USD      24-12-2001 to 12-11-2003    34789   Sheet2
B       778USD      02-04-2003 to 01-03-2004    8765    Sheet2
B       334USD      12-08-2002 to 12-10-2003    12345   Sheet2
```

I have the data of `Letter, Price, Time, Money, Name` as list type variables. But I'm unable to get my head around printing them into my required structure like shown above. I'm a noob in Python. How can I easily achieve this in Python 3? It would be awesome if someone can provide me some help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need `zip`

**Ex:**

```
Letter = ["A", "B"]
Price = ["123USD", "892USD"]
Time = ["01-02-1994 to 01-02-1995", "24-12-2001 to 12-11-2003"]
Money = ["12345", "34789"] 
Name = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2"] 

for letter, price, time, money, name in zip(Letter, Price, Time, Money, Name):
    print('{: <5} {: <5}  {: <5}  {: <5}  {: <5}'.format(letter, price, time, money, name))
```

**Output:**

```
A     123USD  01-02-1994 to 01-02-1995  12345  Sheet1
B     892USD  24-12-2001 to 12-11-2003  34789  Sheet2
```

Comment: I just tried this, it's doing good but it's only printing one record per sheet like in your example. Is there a way that I can print correct number of records as per each sheet  ? Also, can you please tell me is the significance of `{:<5}` there?

Comment: So, apparently `zip` only iterates through the smallest list available in the given input. But here I need to iterate through all the elements in the list with their corresponding sheets. I didn't find a way to do this. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Use `itertools.zip_longest` instead of `zip`

Comment: I checked that out too. But it's not corresponding the records to the correct sheets. But that being said, with your initial answer, I realized something and i'm now trying to make all my list variables be of same length. With that it looks to be going in the correct direction. Thank you very much for your help. I didn't know of `zip` before.